# responsive top navigation only for mobile phones

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have refused to learn responsive coding for years, but now I have reached the point where I have to learn it. Implementing the layout with Flexbox is easy, but I fail at the navigation.

I want to accomplish the following ;
The top navigation should only be shown when the page is accessed by a mobile phone. I did that by setting the PC breakpoint to display: none.

Now I want to remove the actual horizontal PC navigation so that only the toggle navigation is available for the mobile device.

How do I do that?

```css
/*nav*/


/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */

.topnav {
  background-color: rgba(24, 32, 37, 0.3);
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}


/* Add an active class to highlight the current page */

.active {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}


/* Hide the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}


/* Dropdown container - needed to position the dropdown content */

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* Style the dropdown button to fit inside the topnav */

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}


/* Style the dropdown content (hidden by default) */

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(24, 32, 37, 0.7);
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Style the links inside the dropdown */

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}


/* Add a dark background on topnav links and the dropdown button on hover */

.topnav a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}


/* Add a grey background to dropdown links on hover */

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}


/* Show the dropdown menu when the user moves the mouse over the dropdown button */

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}


/* When the screen is less than 600 pixels wide, hide all links, except for the first one ("Home"). Show the link that contains should open and close the topnav (.icon) */

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child),
  .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}


/* The "responsive" class is added to the topnav with JavaScript when the user clicks on the icon. This class makes the topnav look good on small screens (display the links vertically instead of horizontally) */

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {
    float: none;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
}


/*nav*/
```

```html
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Part I
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Part II
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please, could you explain better what do you mean with "remove the horizontal pc navigation"? I tried your code and the menu items disappears, so what else do you want to remove?

Comment: Flexbox is designed to create responsive 1-dimensional lay-outs. An example: https://jsfiddle.net/3fsyxmau/1/. It's not that hard to make it responsive but it does require some setup.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to do it without using javascript is to add this:
It works for the responsive PC navigation as well.

```
 @media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
      .topnav {
        display: none;
      }
    }


    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      .topnav {
        display: block;
      }
```